# Retrieve data from 2 fields with a count from one of them

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve data from a countries table to use for formatting search results but i don't seem to have the correct sql format.

Each country is stored with country_code, country_name, iso_code and sales_location

So for instance it would have 222, United Kingdom, GB, UK Sales

What i need is to be able to query how many times a sales location is listed and what country names are associated with that sales location (Rest of the World has 221 country names)

I tried

```
 SELECT sales_location, countries_name, COUNT( sales_location )
 FROM countries
 GROUP BY sales_location
```

which does give me the locations and counts, but the country name is only giving the first country alphabetically.

Comment: So, there can be only one sales location in one country? Or more? I don't understand what you want ro count, frankly speaking

Comment: I want to know the sales location, what countries names are associated  with that sales location, and a count of how many times a specific sales location is listed

Comment: sales_location contains UK sales, EU sales, Channel Isles Sales and Rest of The World Sales. Specific countries are under each sales_location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sales_location, GROUP_CONCAT(countries_name), COUNT( * )
FROM countries
GROUP BY sales_location
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as it was the first one posted that worked, although the other two answers also give the correct result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT countries_name, GROUP_CONCAT(sales_location) as sales_location,    
 COUNT(sales_location ) as location_count
 FROM countries
 GROUP BY countries_name
```

Comment: This answer does not give the total count of the number of times a sales location is found, only a count of 1 as it is present for every countries_name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sales_location, GROUP_CONCAT(countries_name), COUNT(sales_location)
FROM countries
GROUP BY sales_location
```

This query should help.